# why GET parameters not forwarded to php from nginx for specific urls?

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I'm having a wired problem with NGINX or PHP (Laravel). I don't know what happened to the server. It was working fine and I know I haven't change any configuration on NGINX or PHP.

Problem: When I'm using php `$_GET` to access params then for some reasons on some urls, this variable is empty and for some there is value which I want.

1st URL : `/news/rapido-news?pid=123`
In the above url I'm able to get pid successfully in php.

2nd URL : `/news/amazon-aws-services?pid=432`
In this url I'm not able to get pid from php and if I add more params then still $_GET is empty for this url .

I'm having this issue on multiple urls and some urls working fine.

here is my NGNIX conf file :

```
server {

        root          /home/project/public_html/public;

        #if ($bad_referer) {
        #    return 444;
        #}      i
        if ($http_from != "some_specific_page") {
            return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
        }
        server_name example.com ;

        rewrite ^/((?!blackfridaysale)(?!cybermondaysale)(?!review-competition).*)/$ /$1 permanent;

        keepalive_timeout 3;

        error_log /var/log/nginx/example.error.log;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/example.access.log main buffer=100k flush=5m;
        gzip on;        gzip_types      image/svg+xml  text/plain application/x-javascript text/xml text/css application/javascript;
        gzip_proxied    no-cache no-store private expired auth;
        gzip_min_length 1000;        gzip_vary on;
        open_file_cache max=1000 inactive=20s;
        open_file_cache_valid 30s;        open_file_cache_min_uses 5;
        open_file_cache_errors off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin  $http_origin;
        add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" "true";

        location ~ ^/(rs\/(.+)\/(.*?\.(jpg|png|gif|jpeg|bmp|JPG|PNG|GIF|JPEG|BMP)))\/([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+)$ {
                access_log off; log_not_found off;
                try_files "/images/rs/$2/$5x$6/$3" 404;
                expires 300d;                add_header Pragma "public";
                add_header Cache-Control "public";
                proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie;
                proxy_hide_header "Set-Cookie";
        }

        location ~* \.(ico|css|js|woff|woff2|gif|jpeg|jpg|png|ttf|otf|svg|eot|webp)$ {
                access_log off; log_not_found off;
                rewrite ^(.+)\.(@@hash|\d+)\.(svg|js|css|png|jpg|gif)$ $1.$3 last;

                proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie;
                proxy_hide_header "Set-Cookie";
                expires 300d;
                add_header Pragma "public";
                add_header Cache-Control "public";
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;

        location / {
                root    /home/project/public_html/public;
                try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                root          /home/project/public_html/public;
                fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9001; # php-fpm;
                fastcgi_index  index.php;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include        fastcgi_params;

                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
                #add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
                add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
                add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
                #add_header X-Robots-Tag none;
                #add_header X-Download-Options noopen;
                #add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies none;
                #fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
                #fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
                #fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
                #fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
                proxy_connect_timeout 1200s;
                proxy_send_timeout 1200s;
                proxy_read_timeout 1200s;
                fastcgi_send_timeout 1200s;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 1200s;
        }

}
```

Comment: This `/home/project/public_html/public` is very, very strange. The try_files is fine, it should give you proper pages. There are nginx error logs, try to find your error in there. Show your laravel route for `/news/amazon-aws-services?pid=432`, it goes to a controller, show the relevant part of the controller

Comment: Thanks @UnderDog, but after so many attempts I found that the problem is not with NGINX or laravel, the problem was with cloudfront behaviour :P